# When installing the Flask package offline in Python, there is an error saying that the flit-core<4 version cannot be found

Tags: python, pip

impacket설치시에 필요한 패키지인 flask를 설치하려고 하는데 도와주시면 감사하겠어요.

pip install flask-3.0.2.tar.gz를 실행했어요.

그런데 다음과 같은 오류가 나왔어요.

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(tota=4, connect=NOne, read=None, redirect=None, status=NOne)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3 .connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000288583E9C10>: Failed to establish a new connection : [Errno 11001] getaddr ifo failed')' " /simple/flit-core/

Comment: Your post is rather confusing. Could you show your other Python dependencies in your post? Are you running this from a local machine, or a host, or a Docker container etc?